# ZFS disabling sync writes on dataset

Tags: nfs, zfs, corruption, freenas

I have a freenas box that I use to back  ESX VMs to but don't have a SLOG yet and thus speed is poor due to ESX pushing sync writes to the NFS store on my freenas box.

If I created a separate dataset for the  share and set sync=disabled for just that dataset will I be able to contain corruption to just that dataset if I loose power mid-write or will the entire ZFS pool still be at risk to corruption?

Comment: Surprised you'd ask here and not ServerFault.com

Comment: I completely agree. My bad.   Not sure of the way to get it moved over to ServerFault but I think this is a pretty important question about a common ZFS use case. I have found quite a lot of posts stating that it is very dangerous to enforce sync.  Most posts do not appropriately qualify the actual risks or outline ways to reduce them.

Comment: I'd recommend you read this article on the ZIL and what it really means. [**See here**](http://nex7.blogspot.com/2013/04/zfs-intent-log.html).

Comment: Wow. What a read! Andrew is a very clear writer and definitely one I will follow.  Sure am glad I'm just using FreeNas for read centric or write centric data. I was worried about running VMs and Andrews information confirmed this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Due to a delay in getting a response from this forum, I decided to post the question to the [FreeNAS forums](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/zfs-disabling-sync-writes-on-dataset.39383/#post-243489). Dru Lavignue from iXSystems reponded with the following answer:

> If you set a property on a dataset, only that dataset (and its child datasets that aren't explicitly set differently) is affected by the ramifications of that property.